# SweetAlert2 manual confirm button text while echo'ing JS

Tags: javascript, php

I've echo'ed JS like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { sweetAlert("<b>Great!","Your data is sent successfully.</b>","success");';  
    echo '}, 500);</script>';
```

So, page is printing SweetAlert message after submit. Main question is how to set manual text in confirm button? It is 'OK' by default.

Comment: Have you checked the vendor's documentation for how to use Sweetalert2?

Comment: you can customize your confirm and cancel button, just read documentation
https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/so7afg25/1/

Comment: Yes. It shows how to print out message using "swal" function. But JS I've found looks just different.

Comment: How to echo swal()? I've tried but then page is submitting data without any message.

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'swal({
  text: "Start new case by",
  buttons: true,
  confirmButtonText: "Select Patient?",
  cancelButtonText: "Speed Case?",      
});';

Comment: did you test that?

Comment: Yes, data is being submitted without any message.